# Install Ubuntu over encrypted Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, luks

I am trying to install flavor X over encrypted flavor Y, however, I am not able to decrypt my encrypted flavor Y partition before the installation process. I have used stock encryption of the Ubuntu installer (LUKS)

How can I decrypt my partition then install flavor X over Y ?

*EDIT:* I should mention that I also seek flavor X to be encrypted **while** keeping my personal files on my partition as well

Comment: You could just install it from within the running installation: http://askubuntu.com/q/306282/555486

Comment: Simply use the whole drive (install to the whole drive), which will erase whatever was written on it before.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, I'll try and then post the results. @sudodus See my edit note

Comment: Good luck installing from within the running installation :-) But if that does not work, I suggest that you save your personal files to a separate location (for example `rsync` the `/home` directory to a directory or partition in an external drive). Install the new system. Finally copy those personal files into your new system.