What are the exact command to install desktop packages of each ubuntu flavor?
For Ubuntu, it is sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^. For Xubuntu, it is xubuntu-desktop instead.
But what about Ubuntu Cinnamon or Ubuntu Kylin?
I found that ubuntu-cinnamon-desktop does not exist.
I am looking for an answer which will provide names desktop-packages for all ten flavors of Ubuntu.

The answer can be found in https://askubuntu.com/a/1043847/124466
